# Run Form in C# executable

Tags: c#, express

I am trying to run a code like this:

```
while (true)
{ 
   counter++;
   Form f = new Form1();

   Application.Run(f);
}
```

An infinite loop that configures a `Form1` class which is based on `Form` class and running this `Form` with the command `Application.Run`.

The problem is that for the first time I can get the `Form` visible, but on the next iteration of the loop the Form is not visible.

Anyone?

but, what is the difference between the first time entering the loop in which the Form appears to the next time?
why there is no variable scope issue on the first time?
furthermore, on each new iteration of the loop, i create a new Form1 variable.

Comment: I'm not interested in the answer as much as I'm interested in the reason why you want to do this?

Comment: That's not how Windows Forms works. You don't need a `while(true)` loop. This will continually create new instances of the form. There is already a message loop available to you. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @WhoCares probably to show as many forms as possible to annoy/prank someone, which will probably crash their PC...

Comment: @ChrisF If reading the code as intent, then they want to be able to run their app, and if the application is closed, they start a new instance of the application.  That's behavior that's annoying as hell, IMO.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this would not work, at least not from the code snippet.  The simplest explanation is that it actually *does* work, but the 2nd instance of the form is hidden behind the window of another app.  That's pretty inevitable when you allow your app to have no active window, Windows is forced to find another window to give the focus to.

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to create an infinite instances of the same form?

anyway is this what are you trying to get? 
 check this code

```
while(true){
       new Form1().show();
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
}
```

I set the application to sleep for 1 sec, to show you that it's open a new form..

Edit: I checked your code, and when I tried to close the app it's opening a new form.. 
so as Hans said while there is a form instance windows will set the focus on it.. when you close it.. it will create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

why not do like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread p = new Thread(showform);
    p.Start();
}

private void showform()
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.Show();
}
```